# Partial compilation of openwrt project

Tags: build-process, makefile, openwrt

I would like to get an idea or reference to compile only subset on the openwrt project.
i am aware of the menuconfig utility but this is not enough for my goal.

i would like to compile only the tool-chain (binutils + gcc + glibc) for a specific target (ar71xx) and also the kernel.

now, after looking in the makefiles etc, i have noticed that most of the work in actually patching the toolchain and the kernel and then compile it. is there any option to stop build process after the patching so i can have only the source code patched and i can write my own make file to compile it?

Answer (score 2):

To prepare (patch) toolchain independently:

```
make toolchain/{clean,prepare} V=99
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the kernel source and patch it:

```
make target/linux/{clean,prepare} V=99
```

The patched kernel source will be in build_dir/linux-$(target)/linux-$(version)